# Problema con el comportamiento del VALUE de los inputs

Tags: javascript, html

La lógica de la aplicación es que cuando se da click en un botón de llame a una función y a esta se le pase como argumento lo que haya en la propiedad VALUE del propio botón, hasta haí todo bien, pero cuando quiero usar el VALUE en un if, se comporta como si no tuviera el valor que en realidad tiene. Así que mi pregunta es. ¿Por que ocurre esto y que valor tiene en realidad el value del input?

Adjunto el código:

```js
function ShowAndGetNUmbers(value) {
    console.log(value == "3")
}
```

```html
<input id="3" type="button" value="3" onclick="ShowAndGetNUmbers(value)">
```

El output del código anterior cuando se pulsa el botón es false. Cabe destacar que cuando coloco.

```
cosole.log(typeof(value))
```

El output es string.

Comment: No entiendo el problema... `value` en la función de JS es 3 ¿Qué error te da? el `console.log(value == "3")` te da false? Porque yo lo pruebo y me da true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque en Javascript el [operador `==` es para comparación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality).

Por tanto, lo que haces aquí es preguntar si `value` es igual a `3`:

```
console.log(value == "3")
```

Ponlo así:

```
console.log(value)
```

Pues la idea es imprimir lo que haya en `value`.

### Algunas recomendaciones

Considera evitar el uso de funciones in-line, ya que las mismas hacen depender el código HTML del código Javascript, dificultando el mantenimiento/reutilización del código. Si en un futuro necesitas pasar otro parámetro a la función, y la has puesto in-line en miles de archivos HTML tendrás que ir a buscar esos miles de archivos entre varios miles más y modificar la función.

Es mucho más simple asignar [escucha de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) a los elementos. Si en un futuro hiciera falta alguna modificación, sólo modificarías la función, que se encuentra en una sola parte, pudiendo ser usada por decenas, centenas o miles de archivos. Además, cualquier uso de las propiedades / atributos del elemento es más flexible.

También, evita empezar los `id` de los elementos con valores numéricos, pues en el pasado (HTML 4) hubo problemas con esto, por eso se recomienda que los id empiecen siempre por una letra para asegurar la compatibilidad ([ver la nota de este artículo en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)).

Veamos un ejemplo aplicando las recomendaciones:

```js
let inputThree=document.getElementById("input3");

inputThree.addEventListener('click', ShowAndGetNUmbers, false);

function ShowAndGetNUmbers() {
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(typeof(this));
    console.log(typeof(this.value));    
}
```

```html
<input id="input3" type="button" value="3" />
```